# Installing mongo 10 gen on ubuntu is this the Client, Server, or Both?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I installed mongo on ubuntu using the below for the mongo website.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/debian-sysvinit dist 10gen" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

So...my question is...what did I install?  Is this the client?  The sever?  or both.  If not the server the how to I install?  Same for the client.  In always seems that there are client and server packages.

Thanks

Comment: A bit off topic, using binary distribution is a good way to install mongodb, http://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Comment: I am starting to agree with that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dpkg -L mongodb-10gen` to list the package contents, and you should find both mongo and mongod (client & server).

Comment: Oh...so installed both?  Yes..I see both /usr/bin/mongo and /usr/bin/mongod